# Как по нажатию кнопки (onclick="") спрашивать, передавать и сортировать текст?

Tags: javascript

Имеется такой скрипт для сортировки введенного пользователем текста:

```
var words = prompt('Введите произвольный текст: ').split(' ');
function sortingWords(words) {
for (var i = 0; i < words.length-1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < words.length-1-i; j++) {
        if (words[j+1] < words[j]) {
            var t = words[j+1];
            words[j+1] = words[j];
            words[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(words)
 }
```

В общем,никак не могу додумать как сделать так, чтоб по нажатию кнопки (onclick=""), сначала спрашивало текст, потом передавало введенный текст в функцию, ну и выводило отсортированный массив

Comment: А что сравниваете при сортировке? Первую букву каждого слова?

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев, `words` - это массив строк, а не строка

Comment: @Grundy: `var words = prompt('Введите произвольный текст: ').split(' ');` Вот эта штука сделает массив из слов. Почему уточняю, закрадываются подозрения, что автор хочет по длине слов отсортировать.

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев, ну так _эта штука_ в вопросе и используется, в циклах сравниваются строки, по правилам сравнения строк.

Comment: @Grundy: Я подумал у автора проблема с самой сортировкой как таковой. После редактирования им вопроса - стало яснее.

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев,  по длине тоже необходимо будет сортировать, поэтому буду признателен, за совет в этом направлении

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Небольшое дополнение для ответа @Romario, с сортировкой по длине слов (Если необходимо).

Для сортировки по длине слов можно использовать `.sort()`.

```
function sortingWords(words) {
   return words.sort(function(a , b) {
       return a.length > b.length ? 1 : -1;
   });
   console.log(words)
}
```

Осталось решить, что необходимо делатиь с повторяющимися пробелами, знаками препинания и спецсимволами, так как все они будут учтены.

Answer (score 2):

```js
  function myFunc() { // обработчик события
    var words = prompt('Введите произвольный текст: ')
    .replace(/[.!\?,;:()]/g, "") // убираем из текста ненужные символы
    .split(/\s+/)                // получаем массив слов
    .sort(function (a, b) {      // сортируем, без учета регистра (можно просто sort(), но это будет case sensitive)
      return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
    });

    document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(words); // можно просто console.log() или вернуть
  }

  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', myFunc);
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: при `.split(' ')` возникают дополнительные фантомные элементы массива из пустых строк, если ввести несколько пробелов.

Comment: @Sergiks, предлагаешь регулярку(/\s+/) использовать?

Comment: @Sergiks согласен, плюс ко всему в функции, которую привел автор, в данном случае при разбиении слова будут со знаками препинания и прочими символами. Например, `"Привет, как дела?"` в отсортированном виде будет выглядеть как `["дела?", "как", "Привет,"]`. Я так понимаю, у автора был вопрос именно в том как привязать его функцию к событию.

Comment: @Sergiks в вашей версии`JSON.stringify()` является _case sensitive_ соответственно будет `["Привет,","дела?","как"]`.

Comment: @Romario, в приведенном коде `JSON.stringify()` просто сериализует объект/массив в JSON - он никак не влияет на порядок вывода

Comment: @Grundy да вы правы, извиняюсь.